# Не прохожу авторизацию

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jwt

Разрабатываю авторизацию на сайте с помощью JWT-токенов: передача access токена и его валидация выполняются без ошибок в Postman,

[image: Postman]

```
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .build();
    }

}
```

но при аналогичных действиях в браузере

```
function sendJSON() {
            // с помощью jQuery обращаемся к элементам на странице по их именам
            let login = document.querySelector('#login');
            let password = document.querySelector('#password');
            // а вот сюда мы поместим ответ от сервера
            let result = document.querySelector('.result');
            // создаём новый экземпляр запроса XHR
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // адрес, куда мы отправим нашу JSON-строку
            let url = "http://localhost:8081/person/auth/login";
            // открываем соединение
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            // устанавливаем заголовок — выбираем тип контента, который отправится на сервер, в нашем случае мы явно пишем, что это JSON
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            // когда придёт ответ на наше обращение к серверу, мы его обработаем здесь
            let token;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                // если запрос принят и сервер ответил, что всё в порядке
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    // выводим то, что ответил нам сервер — так мы убедимся, что данные он получил правильно
                    token = JSON.parse(this.responseText).accessToken;
                }
            };
            // преобразуем наши данные JSON в строку
            var data = JSON.stringify({ "login": login.value, "password": password.value });
            // когда всё готово, отправляем JSON на сервер
            xhr.send(data);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/hello/user',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    result.innerHTML = token;
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            });
        }
```

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
    @GetMapping("hello/user")
    public String helloUser(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Личный кабинет");
        return "private";
    }
```

появляется ошибка:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Доступ запрещен
```